# Implementation of a generic factory design pattern

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, factory-method

I like using factory design pattern to inject dependencies, but that means having lots of very similar classes (almost one factory per class). Then I got to an idea to create a generic factory pattern using templates. Something like this:

```
// g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra factory.cpp -o factory


#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>



template < typename T, typename Base = typename T::Iface >
class Factory
{
public:

    template < typename... Args >
    using CreatorFn = std::function< std::shared_ptr< Base > ( Args&&... ) >;

    template < typename... Args >
    static std::shared_ptr< Base > Create( Args&&... args );

    template < typename... Args >
    static void ResetToDefaultCreator();

    template < typename... Args >
    static void SetCreator( CreatorFn< Args... > fn );

private:
    Factory() = delete;

    template < typename... Args >
    static CreatorFn< Args... >& Creator();

    template < typename... Args >
    static std::shared_ptr< Base > DefaultCreator( Args&&... args );
};



template < typename T, typename Base >
template < typename... Args >
std::shared_ptr< Base > Factory< T, Base >::Create( Args&&... args )
{
    return Creator< Args... >()( std::forward< Args >( args )... );
}


template < typename T, typename Base >
template < typename... Args >
void Factory< T, Base >::ResetToDefaultCreator()
{
    CreatorFn< Args... >() = DefaultCreator< Args... >;
}

template < typename T, typename Base >
template < typename... Args >
void Factory< T, Base >::SetCreator( CreatorFn< Args... > fn )
{
    Creator< Args... >() = fn;
}

template < typename T, typename Base >
template < typename... Args >
Factory< T, Base >::CreatorFn< Args... >& Factory< T, Base >::Creator()
{
    static CreatorFn< Args... > creator = DefaultCreator< Args... >;
    return creator;
}

template < typename T, typename Base >
template < typename... Args >
std::shared_ptr< Base > Factory< T, Base >::DefaultCreator( Args&&... args )
{
    return std::make_shared< T >( std::forward< Args >( args )... );
}


struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    using Iface = A;

    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "-- B::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C : public A {
    using Iface = A;

    C( int, float )
    {
    }

    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "-- C::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct D : public A {
    using Iface = A;

    D( int, float )
    {
    }

    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "-- D::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

using FactoryDefaultConstructor = Factory< B >;
using FactoryParamsConstructor  = Factory< C >;

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() : a( FactoryParamsConstructor::Create( 3, 5.7f ) )
    {}

    void foo()
    {
        a->foo();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr< A > a;
};



int main()
{
    FactoryParamsConstructor::ResetToDefaultCreator<int,float>();

    std::shared_ptr< A > obj1 = FactoryParamsConstructor::Create( 3, 5 );
    C* realObj1 = dynamic_cast< C* >( obj1.get() );
    if ( nullptr != realObj1 )
    {
        std::cout << "1 created" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "1 failed" << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass class1;
    class1.foo();

    FactoryParamsConstructor::CreatorFn< int, float > newCretorFn = []( int a,float b ){
                                    std::cout << "****cb called"<<std::endl;
                                    return std::shared_ptr< A >( new D( a, b ) );
                            };
    FactoryParamsConstructor::SetCreator< int, float >( newCretorFn );
    std::shared_ptr< A > obj2 = FactoryParamsConstructor::Create( 3, 5.7f );
    D* realObj2 = dynamic_cast< D* >( obj2.get() );
    if ( nullptr != realObj2 )
    {
        std::cout << "2 created" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "2 failed" << std::endl;
    }

    float p = 5.5f;
    std::shared_ptr< A > obj3 = FactoryParamsConstructor::Create( 3, p );
    D* realObj3 = dynamic_cast< D* >( obj3.get() );
    if ( nullptr != realObj3 )
    {
        std::cout << "3 created" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "3 failed" << std::endl;
    }
    MyClass class2;
    class2.foo();
}
```

Output:

```
1 created
-- C::foo()
****cb called
2 created
3 failed
****cb called
-- D::foo()
```

This works, but with certain problems:

1. if I don't take care what I pass to the `Create()` method, it can fail, since it is going to use wrong instance of the `Creator()` method. Is there a way to fix this? This is the reason why creation of obj3 fails.
2. The SetCreator() method can take only std::function objects. I understand why. My question is, can I change it to take anything appropriate and call correct `Creator()` method?
   Ideally, it would have this declaration:

   `template < typename F >
   static void SetCreator( F fn );`

Then I could do this:

```
std::shared_ptr< A > foo( int, float ) { return new B; };
FactoryParamsConstructor::SetCreator( foo );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do, and posting my solution.

```
template < typename T, typename Base = typename T::Iface >
class Factory
{
public:

    using ReturnType = std::shared_ptr< Base >;
    template < typename... Args >
    using CreatorFn = std::function< ReturnType ( Args... ) >;


    template < typename... Args >
    static ReturnType Create( Args... args )
    {
        return Creator< decltype( args )... >()( args... );
    }

    template < typename... Args >
    static void ResetToDefaultCreator()
    {
        Creator< Args... >() = &DefaultCreator< Args... >;
    }

    template < typename... Args >
    static void SetCreator( CreatorFn< Args... > fn )
    {
        Creator< Args... >() = fn;
    }


private:

    Factory() = delete;

    template < typename... Args >
    static CreatorFn< Args... >& Creator()
    {
        static_assert( ( std::is_same< Args, std::decay_t< Args > >::value && ... ), "None of creator arguments can have a reference.");

        static CreatorFn< Args... > creator = &DefaultCreator< Args... >;
        return creator;
    }

    template < typename... Args >
    static ReturnType DefaultCreator( Args... args )
    {
        return std::make_shared< T >( args... );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `overloaded` is what you want (C++17, but might be implemented for C++11):

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;


const auto Afactory = overloaded {
        []() { return std::make_shared<B>(); },
        [](int a, int b) { return std::make_shared<C>(a, b); },
        [](int a, float b) { return std::make_shared<D>(a, b); },
    };
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ad938d528133b60)

Comment: Maybe that is what I am looking for (I can use c++17). The 2nd I would like to use to instantiate in my application, and 3rd to instantiate a mock in my unit tests. Is it possible to overload in such way? I modified my example just slightly. I would like to create an object in a private of a class. And later I do not have access to the object.

Comment: Actually, that is not what I am looking for. The types in cases 2 and 3 are the same (int, float), not (int, int)

Comment: So you might need 2 factories.

Comment: actually, i just need 1 factory, where I can change the function which creates objects. But since this pattern repeats everywhere, I would like to implement the factory using templates, like in my example.